# UIImageView's properties and constraints get reset when setting image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint

I have a UIImageView on a storyboard with fixed height and leading, top, and trailing constraints.  I modify its alpha and its top constant programmatically to achieve parallax and fading out as an unrelated scrollView pans upwards.  However, whenever I set this imageView's image to a new value, its top constraint and alpha get reset to their storyboard values.

Code snippets follow:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageViewTop: NSLayoutConstraint!

extension ContentTableController: UIScrollViewDelegate {

    /* Creating parallax by modifying the top constant, 
    and also fading out image as scrollView scrolls up.  
    Note the imageView is NOT in the scrollView in question. */

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let height = featuredPoster.frame.size.height
        let percentScrolled: CGFloat = max(1 - offsetY / height, 0)
        let parallaxFraction: CGFloat = 0.3
        imageView.alpha = percentScrolled
        imageViewTop.constant = -offsetY * parallaxFraction
    }
...
}
...

// Called elsewhere
func setsImage() {
    // setting its image resets the view's alpha and the value of its top constant
    imageView.image = nil // setting to nil, but could be any value
}
```

Comment: You must have some other code at work... I just ran a quick test with your code, calling `setsImage()` from a button tap, and the `imageView` stays where it is and maintains its `.alpha`. Try creating a fresh View Controller, add and setup a Scroll View and Image View... connect your code, and you should see it's not a problem. Then, try to find what else your full code is doing that could cause the "reset".

Comment: Interesting .. nice catch.  Ostensibly I'm not doing any related code anywhere else.  The origin of the call that changes the image comes from a uicollectionviewdelegate.  I wonder now if I might not be setting this image on the main queue, and whether or not that could cause this.

Comment: Wasn't a thread safety issue, seemingly.  @DonMag, any specific settings in the storyboard that you're using?

Comment: Nope, nothing special at all. When whatever is going on in your collection view that calles `setsImage()`, have you checked to see if your `scrollViewDidScroll()` func being triggered with a `.contentOffset.y` value of `0`?

Comment: You called it.  I put a breakpoint on scrollViewDidScroll ... I'm have other scrollViews using this same delegate.  One is self-animating, and since I'm not verifying which scrollView is calling the method, it has the appearance of resetting the values.  setsImage() is also tied to this animation.  Operator error strikes again >.<

Answer (score 0):

PEBCAK

**scrollViewDidScroll(...)** should verify which scrollView making the call if you have different scrollviews that call the same delegate methods.

In this case, I have a UICollectionView whose delegate is set.  Note that **UICollectionViewDelegate** encompasses **UIScrollViewDelegat**e.

A solution would be

```
// The scrollView that you expect is calling the delegate method.
var desiredScrollView: UIScrollView! 
   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        //Verify this is the correct scrollView to trigger this code
        guard scrollView == desiredScrollView else { return }

        let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let height = featuredPoster.frame.size.height
        let percentScrolled: CGFloat = max(1 - offsetY / height, 0)
        let parallaxFraction: CGFloat = 0.3
        imageView.alpha = percentScrolled
        imageViewTop.constant = -offsetY * parallaxFraction
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try lowering its content hugging and compression:

```
someImage.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 249), for: .horizontal)
someImage.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 249), for: .horizontal)
someImage.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 249), for: .vertical)
someImage.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 249), for: .vertical)
```

Comment: Error was actually in my code in this case.  Thanks for the feedback, though!